# Keep draggable in its list while dragging (react-beautiful-dnd)

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

How can i keep draggable in it's original list while dnd action in progress? E.g. i want to drag item "copy" and hold it's original where it was at the same time. After `onDragEnd` i can copy data, but while dragging it looks wrong and can confuse users. (Did not find example in official list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by rendering additional list item copy (with transformation turned off) down in list.

This sample code from docs

```
<Draggable ...> {(provided, snapshot) => ( <MyItemDraggable .../> )} </Draggable>
```

Become something like this

```
<Draggable ...> {(provided, snapshot) => ( <> <MyItemDraggable .../>  {snapshot.isDragging ? <MyItemDraggable className={`dnd-copy`} .../> : null} </>)} </Draggable>
```

Note new fake draging-time item with dnd-copy class

```
.dnd-copy ~ div {
    transform: none !important;
}
```

Empty tags are also needed for this solution

Comment: The clone and the original item disappears after drop.

Comment: This answer put me in the direction of a solution. Also found this code sample that was helpful on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-beautiful-dnd-copy-and-drag-jkntp?file=/index.js One thing that was messing me up is I was passing all the react dnd props to the `dnd-copy` item, be sure not to do that.

Comment: saw this sample. it uses pretty old version of react-beautiful-dnd. also it is last version of react-beautiful-dnd suitable for this solution. sure, my solution based on this.